# How get a sorted list combined with group

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I try to get a list of product-groups sorted by group.
My problem is that i need only the one product into a group that is available( 0=no, 1=yes ) and with the lowest price and amount>0.

```
select id, group_id, price, amount, available from products
Table rows:



   id  group_id price amount available
    1  1     100   1      1
    2  1     50    1      1
    3  1     25    1      0
    4  2     100   2      1
    5  2     200   1      1
    6  2     100   2      1
    7  2     50    1      1
```

I need the rows with id 2 and 7 as the result.
My problem is into a group_id there are more than one id with the same price.

Any ideas to solve this without subselects?

Comment: i have edit the question. group to group_id. That are not the real names into by database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ANSI standard and should return what you want. If there are multiple rows matching the criteria (ie with the same minimu price) it will return only the first one (lower id).

```
SELECT MIN(P.id),  P.group_id, P.price, P.amount, P.available
FROM products P
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT group_id, MIN(price) AS minprice
     FROM products 
     WHERE available=1 AND amount > 0
     GROUP BY group_id
   ) G ON P.group_id = G.group_id AND P.price = G.minprice                            
GROUP BY P.group_id, P.price, P.amount, P.available
ORDER BY P.group_id
```

Note that if you have a large table you might need to index the price column (or a composite index group_id + price)

It would have been simpler on other RDBMS that supports window functions

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I will try it on a production table. It looks good at the moment on my testtable.

Comment: This is the basic solution to solved the given problem. Based on this i can solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause and [MIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) on the [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   group_id INT NOT NULL,
   price INT NOT NULL,
   amount INT NOT NULL,
   available INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products (id, group_id, price, amount, available) VALUES (1, 1, 100, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO products (id, group_id, price, amount, available) VALUES (2, 1, 50 , 1, 1);
INSERT INTO products (id, group_id, price, amount, available) VALUES (3, 1, 25 , 1, 0);
INSERT INTO products (id, group_id, price, amount, available) VALUES (4, 2, 100, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO products (id, group_id, price, amount, available) VALUES (5, 2, 200, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO products (id, group_id, price, amount, available) VALUES (6, 2, 100, 2, 1);

SELECT id, group_id, price, amount, available FROM products;

SELECT id, group_id, price, amount, available
FROM products
WHERE amount > 0
AND available = 1
GROUP BY group_id HAVING min(price);
```

Comment: INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `group_id`, `price`, `amount`, `available`)
VALUES
 (7, 2, 50, 1, 1);
Then you shoud have id 1 and 7. But i get id 1 and 4

Comment: OK @harley81, I can start a mysql with your configuration right now, I was testing with sqlite and i get 2 and 7 ;) So, I think maybe needs a JOIN if you do not want a subselect